# Getting wrong file creation date & vnode creation date in user process and kauth system respectively

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, kernel-extension

I am using kauth system to monitor file specific changes.
In my KAUTH_FILEOP_SCOPE listener when I am getting any notification I send(enqueue) it to the user process.
In the user process when I tried to access file creation date using

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
```

it came as 1 Jan 1904.

I tried passing vnode creation time to user process in KAUTH_FILEOP_CLOSE case
It is also 1 Jan 1904.

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:-2082844800];
```

And if I introduce sleep in user process for suppose 2 to 3 seconds. I am getting correct creation date.

Why system behaving like that?
Weather I am doing any thing wrong?

I have searched and do many R&D to find solution but no success.
What will be the solution as I do not want sleep in my program?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that the kauth event fires before the file has been fixed up. Can you not use kevents or a similar notification mechanism instead? I suspect that would fire at a later stage.

Comment: Actually I have to use kauth scope only. So trying to find solution within it.